# xcode tableview scroll to position

Tags: objective-c, xcode, scroll, tableview, uitableview

I try to program a tableview, where each cell contains its own textfield. When the user selects a textfield, the tableview should scroll, until the cell, which contains the selected textfield, is on the top of the visible part of the tableview. How can I do that?

Comment: Swift or Objective-C ? Please tag appropriately.

Comment: Objective-C is the language

Comment: OK - I've added a tag for you now - please remember to add appropriate tags on future questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your cellForRowAtIndexPath, give tag to your every textfield like,

```
[[cell myTextField] setTag:[indexPath row]];
[[cell myTextField] setDelegate:self] ;
```

Implement UITextField Delegate method :

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:textField.tag inSection:0]
    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES]
}
```

Comment: When I set self as delegate there appears this message: Sending 'TableViewController *const_strong' to parameter of incompatible type 'id<UITextfieldDelegate>'

Comment: I added the UITextfieldDelegate and it worked, thanks